# Como mostrar/ocultar password con el icono del ojo

Tags: jquery

Hay que hacer, con jQuery,
un formulario donde se pida usuario, contraseña, volver_a_escribir_contraseña y el botón de enviar.

Las contraseñas estarán ocultas *********

Pero al clicar un botón (por ejemplo con forma de ojo) queremos que se vea lo que se está escribiendo

Al hacer clic en enviar, sólo haremos un mensaje escrito avisando que las dos contraseñas no coinciden (en su caso).

Answer (score 2):

Le cambias el tipo de input, de password a text

```js
jQuery('#clickme').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('#elpassword').attr('type', function(index, attr) {
    return attr == 'text' ? 'password' : 'text';
  })
})
```

```css
#clickme {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=elpassword type=password value=unsecreto placeholder=password />
<svg id=clickme width=28 height=25 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M569.354 231.631C512.97 135.949 407.81 72 288 72 168.14 72 63.004 135.994 6.646 231.631a47.999 47.999 0 0 0 0 48.739C63.031 376.051 168.19 440 288 440c119.86 0 224.996-63.994 281.354-159.631a47.997 47.997 0 0 0 0-48.738zM288 392c-102.556 0-192.091-54.701-240-136 44.157-74.933 123.677-127.27 216.162-135.007C273.958 131.078 280 144.83 280 160c0 30.928-25.072 56-56 56s-56-25.072-56-56l.001-.042C157.794 179.043 152 200.844 152 224c0 75.111 60.889 136 136 136s136-60.889 136-136c0-31.031-10.4-59.629-27.895-82.515C451.704 164.638 498.009 205.106 528 256c-47.908 81.299-137.444 136-240 136z"/></svg>
<!--
Font Awesome Free 5.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
-->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que yo buscaba pero con el ojo dentro del input.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto es lo que estás buscando. Te ofrezco 2 soluciones:

**SIN BOOTSTRAP**

```js
$("#imgContrasena").click(function () {

  var control = $(this);
  var estatus = control.data('activo');

  var image = control.find('img');
  if (estatus == false) {
  
    control.data('activo', true);
    $(image).attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/show-and-hide-password/100/show_hide_password-10-256.png');
    $("#txtPassword").attr('type', 'text');
  }
  else {
  
    control.data('activo', false);
    $(image).attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/show-and-hide-password/100/show_hide_password-09-256.png');
    $("#txtPassword").attr('type', 'password');
  }
});
```

```css
.input_container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.control {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input_container">
    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="control" value="contraseña">
    <span id="imgContrasena" data-activo=false><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/show-and-hide-password/100/show_hide_password-09-256.png" class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

**CON BOOTSTRAP**

```js
$("#imgContrasena").click(function () {

  var control = $(this);
  var estatus = control.data('activo');
  
  var icon = control.find('span');
  if (estatus == false) {
  
    control.data('activo', true);
    $(icon).removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open').addClass('glyphicon-eye-close');
    $("#txtPassword").attr('type', 'text');
  }
  else {
  
    control.data('activo', false);
    $(icon).removeClass('glyphicon-eye-close').addClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
    $("#txtPassword").attr('type', 'password');
  }
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-control + .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 8px 27px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-3">
   <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" value="contraseña"/>
   <!--<span id="imgContrasena" data-activo=false><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></span>-->
   <span id="imgContrasena" data-activo=false class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
</div>
```